# Twitter rate limit using twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I often get an exception "Rate limit exceeded" when using method Twitter.getFollowersIDs() using twitter4j library. Before calling this method I check if I did not exceeded the rate limit already like this:

```
if(Twitter.getRateLimitStatus().get("/followers/ids").getRemaining() > 0)
```

If I try to use method `getRateLimitStatus("/followers/ids")`, I get an error

```
{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you setup authentication? See: http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html

Comment: see my answer here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28656382/rate-limit-exceeded-with-twitter4j/28657130#28657130

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the error is misleading (possibly because an earlier error in the getRemaining() is not properly thrown).
The way I did it was along the lines of

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(twitter.getRateLimitStatus().get("/followers/ids"));
    try {
        int remaining = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.get("remaining").toString());
        if (remaining == 0)
        {
            int secondsUntilReset = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.get("secondsUntilReset").toString());
            System.out.println("Waiting for seconds: ".concat(jsonObject.get("secondsUntilReset").toString()));
            Thread.sleep((( secondsUntilReset ) * 1000));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and so on...